# Thumbnail for my Pen doesn't get updated when the contents of the Pen is updated in CodePen

Tags: codepen

So, whenever you create a pen on `Codepen`, it assigns a screenshot to your pen, which acts as a thumbnail to represent that pen in your dashboard.

But the problem that I am facing is that when I update the Pen (*or change its look*), then the thumbnail associated with the pen should also get updated, but that is not the case with me.

It used to happen earlier that with the change in content, the thumbnail would also get updated, but it doesn't happen anymore.

*I would like to know has anyone else also faced this issue and is there any fix to it. NOTE: I am not a PRO member so I cannot assign custom screenshots to my pens.*

Comment: It happens to me to, they have added an update in there blog (https://blog.codepen.io/2020/07/21/lazy-loading-and-srcset-images-in-the-grid/) i guess something is wrong there.

Comment: @Crezzur Will this fix this issue? I guess they only did some performance tweaks. I haven't tried it recently so I can't tell whether or not its fixed. Please let me know if its fixed. I also noticed some weird behavior that the screenshot for the pen is different and the screenshot that it shows on my dashboard is different, don't know why.

Comment: No its not a fix but an update, i guess they have some bugs with it.

Comment: @Crezzur Is there any way we can report this bug to Codepen?

Comment: You can use this form: https://codepen.io/support/

Answer (score -1):

I dont know how it actually works, but it usually takes screenshot when you save a pen, you can try to copy all your code to the new pen and save it at once (I've tried that and it works for me), or you can easily just be a pro member.